# Loopback with Suricata

Tags: ids, snort, suricata

Is there any way of analyzing loopback traffic with Suricata?

I am trying it this way without success:

```
root@security-onion:/home/sar/TFM/alerts/suricata# suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i lo -l . -k none
7/9/2018 -- 19:32:25 - <Notice> - This is Suricata version 4.0.5 RELEASE
7/9/2018 -- 19:32:29 - <Warning> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_SYSCALL(50)] - Failure when trying to set feature via ioctl for 'lo': Operation not supported (95)
7/9/2018 -- 19:32:29 - <Notice> - all 2 packet processing threads, 4 management threads initialized, engine started.
7/9/2018 -- 19:32:29 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_INVALID_VALUE(130)] - Frame size bigger than block size
7/9/2018 -- 19:32:29 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Couldn't init AF_PACKET socket, fatal error
7/9/2018 -- 19:32:29 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_FATAL(171)] - thread W#01-lo failed
```

This is the suricata configuration file: [suricata.yaml](https://uses0-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/pabtensan_alum_us_es/EW8D6iTMX_ZFtL-l6IGN6r4BPyVMlZEFzDDIeASucqfP5w?e=eIco6i)

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna run in `Pcap` live mode then you should turn-ff `AF_PACKET` mode from suricata configuration file: `suricata.yaml`.

```
# Linux high speed capture support
af-packet:
  - interface: lo
```

you got error because of af-packet packet capturing mode, probably not configure properly.

```
7/9/2018 -- 19:32:29 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Couldn't init AF_PACKET socket, fatal error
```